# Select de duas tabelas sem repetir dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas, uma de utilizadores e outra de fotos onde cada linha contem o id de utilizador da respetiva foto.

Quero selecionar os dados de utilizador e pegar as fotos pelo id de utilizador da tabela fotos.

Desta maneira ele retorna me os dados duplicados da tabela utilizador porque o utilizador contém varias fotos na tabela fotos.

Como poderei apenas pegar uma vez os dados do utilizador(tabela user) e  todas as fotos a que ele pertencem da fotos(tabela photo), que o utilizador(`user_id`) contém na tabela photos?

```
$sql = "SELECT  u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao, p.user_id, p.location 

FROM user AS u 

INNER JOIN photos AS p

ON u.id=p.user_id


";
```

Comment: David você já tentou usar o "select distinct"

Comment: já sim,mas o retorno é o mesmo

Comment: Mas você quer as fotos, certo? Se você quer as fotos e precisa do local delas `p.local` então ao fazer o join você vai ter que ter o dados do usuário para cada linha. Pensa no mundo real, cada foto tem um user, logo, cada linha do SQL vem uma foto diferente e cada uma delas tem um user, só que no seu caso o user é o mesmo...

Comment: Eu entendi que ele não queria as fotos, mas a quantidade. Entendi isso por essa frase retirada da pergunta: "e a totalidade das fotos(tabela photo) que o utilizador(user_id) contém na tabela photos".

Comment: @cantoni, eu percebi isso também, mas também vi o `p.local` ali, aí resolvi deixar o comentário para ver qual das duas coisas ele precisa na verdade. No caso a totalidade que ele quis dizer pode ser todas as fotos e não um count... Como você já tinha colocado o count na resposta eu só falei do caso do `p.local`

Comment: @Ricardo queria apenas a informação do utilizador e todas as fotos do próprio utilizador. So as fotos se podem repetir porque o utilizador pode ter várias fotos.

Comment: David, você quer o total de foto apenas, tipo, utilizador david tem 50 fotos ou quer os detalhes de todas as fotos?

Comment: o `p.location` é o diretorio das fotos, não tem problema. elas sao exibidas com a query q eu tenho. so que para cada linha de foto ele duplica os dados do utilizador

Comment: @ricardo quero receber as informações do utilizador e todas as fotos que pertencem a ele. Essa query, retorna as informações do utilizador duplicados porque ele tem 2 fotos, por exemplo. Se o utilizador tiver 4 fotos, vêm as 4 fotos mais 4x o username, por ex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que você deseja saber são os dados do utilizador e a quantidade de fotos que existe pra cada um, então esse SQL deve resolver:

```
SELECT  u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao, count(*)
FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN photos AS p
ON u.id=p.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao
```

Answer (score 2):

Estou colocando uma resposta porque no comentário vai ficar muito ruim fazer a tabela que quero colocar de exemplo.

O que você está dizendo que é um problema na verdade é o "certo". Vamos a um exemplo pratico:

Utilizador Ricardo tem 5 fotos:

Ao fazer o SQL o retorno é:

```
u.id   u.username   p.user_id   p.location
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto1)
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto2)
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto3)
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto4)
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto5)
```

Isso é o resultado atual:

O que você está pedindo é para ficar assim:

```
u.id   u.username   p.user_id   p.location
1      Ricardo      1           (local foto1)
null   null         1           (local foto2)
null   null         1           (local foto3)
null   null         1           (local foto4)
null   null         1           (local foto5)
```

Isso não seria o correto.

Se você quiser somente os dados das fotos faz um SQL direto nas fotos:

```
select * from photos where user_id = 1
```

Não é errado ele retornar os dados duplicados se você faz o join das duas tabelas.

Entendeu?

Comment: Ok, isso esta certo. Mas eu também quero receber a informação do utilizador.

selecionar o utilizador id=1 e receber todas as fotos que existem do utilizador na tabela photos($user_id=1).

Comment: O seu SQL da pergunta fazer exatamente o que você está dizendo, traz tudo do utilizador e pegar todas as fotos dele, e vem no formado da primeira tabela dessa resposta, que você acabou de dizer (Ok, isso esta certo). Concorda?

Comment: Sim, o SQL da minha pergunta retorna tudo. As informações do utilizador e as fotos todas que pertencem ao utilizador. Como no seu primeiro exemplo. Ele tem 5 fotos e repete 5x o username

Comment: Então, entendeu que o que você tem é o correto?

Comment: Para ele não repetir eu teria que fazer uma query so para a saida do utilizador e então fazer uma outra query para selecionar as photos do utilizador que saiu na primeira query?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Agora, quanto ao certo ou errado de fazer duas consultas ou uma só como está vai de cada um.

Answer (score 0):

use o select distinct.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local,u.descricao, p.user_id, p.location 

FROM user AS u 

INNER JOIN photos AS p

ON u.id=p.user_id


";
```